# Add one file output.dat to multiple files with number file1.dat file2.dat... file30.dat using bash

Tags: linux, shell

I have multiple files with name file1.dat file2.dat ... file30.dat. I want to add content of each of the files to another file named bnd.dat and give new names of those files such as bnd1.dat bnd2.dat etc. using bash script. Can one please help me with the command. Thank you.

Comment: Without examples, it's not quite clear what you're trying to achieve. Also please show what you have tried. Otherwise, you risk receiving downvotes.

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/ - please see [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). Otherwise, try: `for i in {1..30]; do cat bdn.dat file$i.dat >bnd$i.dat; done`

Comment: Dear All, Thanks for your comments. I clarify there again for your reference. I have a file1.dat file and another file bnd.dat. I want to merge two files to generate new file. I have now another file names file2.dat to merge with the file bnd.dat. Then I have more such file file3.dat, file4.dat and each of them should be merged with the bnd.dat file. I want to use a script (bash) to generate those new files. Thanks you. Also, the suggestion by Mr. Paul Hodges did not help. It does not produce multiple files.